# Why is `x[i]` not equivalent to `x.__getitem__(x)`?

Tags: python, magic-methods, syntactic-sugar

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names):

> `x[i]` is roughly equivalent to `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)`.

What is the benefit of the above rather than having a seemingly simpler `x.__getitem__(i)`?
EDIT: Why is Python behaving this way?

As a downside of the standard behavior let me show this sample code where I was surprised to find the last assertion fails while second to last one (calling `__getitem__` directly) passes.

```
def poww_bar(base):
    class Bar():
        def __getitem__(self, x):
            return lambda: base**x
    return Bar()

def poww_foo(base):
    class Foo():
        pass
    f = Foo()
    f.__getitem__ = lambda x: lambda: base ** x
    return f

pow_bar2 = poww_bar(2)
pow_foo2 = poww_foo(2)


assert pow_bar2.__getitem__(3)() == 8 # OK
assert pow_bar2[3]() == 8 # OK

assert pow_foo2.__getitem__(3)() == 8 # OK
assert pow_foo2[3]() == 8 # TypeError: 'Foo' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It failed probably because it takes more than just `f.__getitem__ = ...` to define the indexing operator. Maybe when you do `def __getitem__(...): ...` the interpreter does some behind the scenes magic to register this function as special and eligible to use indexing syntactic sugar

Comment: Moreover your `f.__getitem__` version belongs only to a single instance `f` of `Foo`, not the whole class (and it accepts 1 parameter, in contrast to `(self, x)` in standard version)

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov It seems that OP is aware of this and is asking *why* Python behaves that way.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are *class* attributes, not instance attributes.

There is no instance attribute named `__getitem__` associated with `pow_bar2`. So lookup proceeds to checking the class for an attribute by that name, and it succeeds in finding `Bar.__getitem__`.

But the process doesn't end there. `pow_bar2.__getitem__(i)` is not equivalent to `Bar.__getitem__(i)`, because Python first checks of the attribute lookup produces an object that implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Since `Bar.__getitem__` is an instance of `function`, it *does* implement the descriptor protocol.

The next step is then to return not the function itself, but the result of `Bar.__dict__['__getitem__'].__get__(pow_bar2, Bar)`. (I'm switching to the use of `Bar.__dict__` to emphasize that we do not get into an infinite loop of triggering the descriptor protocol.) This is an instance of `method`, which is itself a callable that passes is own arguments, along with `pow_bar2`, as arguments to the original function.

Thus, `pow_bar2.__getitem__(i)` is equivalent to `Bar.__dict__['__getitem__'].__get__(pow_bar2, Bar)(i)`, which is roughly equivalent to `Bar.__dict__['__getitem__'](pow_bar2, i)`.

---

But really, `pow_bar2[i]` is just shorter and more easily recognizable (due to decades of established support for this syntax in other languages) than `pow_bar2.__getitem__(i)`. `__getitem__` is what makes the use of `[]` *extendable* to other classes, rather than limiting it to built-in types.

---

The descriptor protocol is not just a one-shot feature that makes instance-method behavior seem more complicated than necessary. It also determines how class methods, static methods, and properties work, and can further be used to customize attribute behavior in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be an optimization.  A class function will only have one reference in the class definition.  An object function will have a reference in every object.  So the `__getitem__` method was specified to be a class function, so they didn't need to waste time looking in the object definitions for it.

This is all speculation of course.